# Load xml gzipped from external link

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I need to load a gzipped xml from an external link but I don't know how to do it. 
Now I'm loading this xml file to my server and then I change every 3 days the xml adress in the variable.

The code I'm using now for loading xml is this:

```
$xmlFile= new SimpleXMLElement('xml/abcd_201407281213_12074_28203833.xml', 0, true);
```

The link gived to me to download the xml file from their server is like this:

```
http://nameofthewebsite.com/folder/28203833C78648187.xml?ticket=BA57F0D9FF910FE4DB517F4EC1A275A2&gZipCompress=yes
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: It's not quite clear which part of the process you are having problems with. Are you looking for a way of accessing/downloading from a URL? Or is the gzip part the problem? And does the code you've pasted have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @IMSoP the problems are both. I need to download a gzipped xml from an external website and I need to extract it for working on simplexml